# Changing route path in MemoryRouter in Enzyme tests

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a component which listens to the history being changed by creating a wrapper in Enzyme which places my component within a `MemoryRouter`; i.e.:

```
mount(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={'/path/param1}>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/path"
        component={MyComponent}
      />
  </Switch>
</MemoryRouter>
)
```

For the initial path, this works fine, however, I specifically want to test what happens when it starts at say `/path/param1` but then the history is changed to `/path/param2`

The monitoring of the path is being done by wrapping the component's export with `withRouter`, like this:

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

And then upon construction, I am using `history.listen` to subscribe to the history changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a base `<Route>` component with a custom `history` object to do this.

First, install the `history` package (to devDevpendencies if you are only using it in tests).

In your test file:

```ts
// we are using memory history only
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then, setup your component like so: (you can drop the `Switch` if there is only one route)

```ts
const history = createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries: ['/path/param1'],
});

// mount with custom history object
mount(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route
      path="/path"
      component={MyComponent}
    />
  </Router>
)
```

Later in your test, you can check what's the current location of the `history` after your component does its thing.

```ts
// check current path has been changed
expect(history.entries[0].pathname).to.eq('/path/param2');
```

You can find all the other stuff you can get access to with `history` here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history